# Bootstrap footer issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer

On my website I am using bootstrap however my footer is not staying at the bottom of the page. How can this be solved? My website is http://www.kewsplus.com/chunetest/blog.html to see the error. The footer is at the base but covers some of the text in the webpage also the images are not in its correct position. On the home page you can see what the footer actually is supposed to look like

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I saw your css through firebug there have to extra property in Wrap and footer css. You can remove margin from Wrap and remove height from Footer.

**Old Css**

```
#wrap {
  height: auto !important;
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

footer {
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   height: 60px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

**Updated css**

```
#wrap {
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 100%;
}  
footer {
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **Bootstrap Navbar** for you footer, like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
    ...
</nav>
```

See here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-bottom

You could also add a margin:

```
#wrap {
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: -60px 0 auto -60px;
}
```

But I encourage you to use the Bootstrap footer if you're using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The footer is at the bottom of the page in Chrome, though I can't scroll the page. I'm not sure what you're asking.

The likely reason you can't make your font bold is that you haven't included a bold version of it in the page. If I do this it works fine:

```
p {
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

You'll need to link a heavy-weight version of 'Open Sans' in your stylesheet.

Comment: its at the bottom but it is covering text. So all the text is not showing on the page.